# CRC calculation with different buffers

Tags: c

I'm calculating a simple XOR CRC for a data transmission.
The function is:

```
static char calc_crc(unsigned char *data, unsigned len)
{
    char crc = 0;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < len; i++ )
        crc = crc ^ data[i];
    return crc;
}
```

My problem is:

How can I call this function with data from two seperate buffers?

E.g.

```
unsigned char buf1[...] = { 0x1, 0x3, 0x43, 0x1, 0x0, 0x40 }
unsigned char buf2[...] = { 0x1, 0x8, 0x44, 57, 0x00 }
```

I want to call my crc function **once**, and the calculation must be the content from buf1 and buf2 combined together.

Thx!

EDIT:
As user Michael Walz wrote, the combined buffer would be

```
unsigned char bufcombined[...] = { 0x1, 0x3, 0x43, 0x1, 0x0, 0x40, 0x1, 0x8, 0x44, 57, 0x00 }
```

and from this buffer I would like to do the XOR calculation.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you "want to calculate the XOR CRC of both buffers together"? Do you mean that you should combine the contents of both buffers somehow? That you want to call the function twice, once for each buffer? Combine the return value of two calls? Something else? Please elaborate.

Comment: I want to call the function once, and calculate the CRC with the content of both buffers.

Comment: You should be able to find out this by yourself. This is really very simple.

Comment: Then you can't. Not unless you modify the function to take *both* buffers (and their respective length) as arguments, and also provide some way to "return" the results for both buffers. One possible solution is to make a wrapper function which calls the `calc_crc` function for both buffers.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I'm really sorry, but I really don't know how to do it. If I knew it, I wouldn't asked...

Comment: @trek can you edit your question with a very simple example of 2 buffers and the desired result ? Your question alread has 2 votes for closing because of "unclear what your are asking".

Comment: Call it for one, call it for the other, xor the returned values together.

Comment: The only other, more correct, way would be to modify the function to take an initializer char.

Comment: Still not quite clear, so the CRC of both buffers combined would be the crc of this  : `unsigned char bufcombined[...] = { 0x1, 0x3, 0x43, 0x1, 0x0, 0x40, 0x1, 0x8, 0x44, 57, 0x00 }` ? Please edit your quastion and put the desired result.

Comment: Also, Cyclic Redundancy Check is a type of error detection code. XOR is a different type of error detection code. So `calc_crc` doesn't calculate a CRC at all. From a clarity perspective, I suggest you choose a different function name, and edit the post (maybe CRC->checksum?) so it becomes more relevant when it turns up in search results.

Comment: Oh... I missed the 'I want to call my crc function once' homework tell:(

Comment: Oh - I missed it because it was edited in.  Great, I wonder what silly constraint is going to be added next?

Comment: As @SigveKolbeinson wrote, the term CRC is a commonly accepted term for a specific algorithm. Please choose a different one for your linear bit-checksum. (Note: that algorithm does not add much to error detection; such were used in the 80ies when clock cycles and ROM were rare. I'd recommend either to use a true CRC or at least some true checksum on bytes instead of bits.). If using a table, CRC are almost as fast as your thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. concatenate the buffers first, and then call your function once

   this is *stupid*, but the only way to do literally what you asked
2. just call the function twice, like

   ```
   char crc = calc_crc(buf1, len1) ^ calc_crc(buf2, len2);
   ```

   this ignores your requirement that

   > I want to call my crc function once

   but you never explained why, and it seems like a daft requirement
3. rewrite the function to take an array of buffers and an array of lengths. This also seems silly, unless you're often going to be calling it with an `iovec` or something
4. other, even more elaborate ways of doing something simple ...

Comment: Yeah.. I missed the 'call only once' homework-constraint:(

Answer (score 0):

Use an initializer parameter:

```
static char calc_crc(char init, unsigned char *data, unsigned len)
{
     for ( int i = 0 ; i < len; i++ )
        init = init ^ data[i];
    return init;
}
```

Then you can do result=calc_crc(calc_crc(0,buffer1,buffer1len), buffer2, buffer2len);

Answer (score -1):

You can call the function like this:

```
combinedcrc = calc_crc(buf1, 11);  // 11 being the sum of the lengths of buf1 and buf2
```

But this requires that:

1. `buf2` is declared directly after `buf1` like in your question
2. your compiler puts `buf1` and `buf2` directly one after the other in memory without any padding. This is often the case, but the compiler may very well arrange the two buffers differently in memory.

So technically this is undefined behaviour.